# Get all the data from an Array

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have an API which was developed using Laravel and i am trying to pass the data into vue js to display it.

The data is like this

```
electData: Object
  category: Array[3]
      0: Object
       cat_desc: modified
       category_id: 95
       cost: 56
       kwh_used: 99
      1: Object
       cat_desc: modified
       category_id: 95
       cost: 56
       kwh_used: 99
     2: Object
       cat_desc: modified
       category_id: 95
       cost: 56
       kwh_used: 99
```

And i tried to render it by using v-for

```
 <tr> 
                                    <td class="clickOption" @click="first">{{ (electCats.category[0].cat_desc) }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ electCats.category[0].kwh_used }}</td>
                                    <td>£{{ electCats.category[0].cost }}</td> 
                                 </tr>
```

The above code display the first object in the array.

My question is that how do i get the 2nd, 3rd etc in the array because when i do this

```
 <tr>  
                                    <td class="clickOption" @click="second">{{ (electCats.category[1].cat_desc) }}</td>
                                   <td>{{ electCats.category[1].kwh_used }}</td>
                                    <td>£{{ electCats.category[1].cost }}</td>
                                </tr>
```

I get error `[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cat_desc')"`

How can i avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'cat_desc')"

As per the error, It seems you are trying to access an `object` from `category` array which is not available.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      electData: {
        category: [{
          cat_desc: 'Description 1',
          category_id: 1,
          cost: 51,
          kwh_used: 97
        }, {
          cat_desc: 'Description 2',
          category_id: 2,
          cost: 52,
          kwh_used: 98
        }, {
          cat_desc: 'Description 3',
          category_id: 3,
          cost: 53,
          kwh_used: 99
        }]
      },
      filteredData: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getCategoryDetails(categoryId) {
        this.filteredData = this.electData.category.filter((obj) => obj.category_id === categoryId)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-for="category in electData.category" :key="category.category_id" style="border: 1px solid black" @click="getCategoryDetails(category.category_id)">
    {{ category.category_id }}
  </button>
  <table>
    <tr v-for="category in filteredData" :key="category.category_id"> 
      <td>{{ (category.cat_desc) }}</td>
      <td>{{ category.kwh_used }}</td>
      <td>£{{ category.cost }}</td> 
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Jindal the solution you provided works but what i am talking about is that apart from category there is another data with it which is ```electData``` as parent with data1, data2 data3 which has cat_id in them and belongs to the category. How do i ensure that when a category is clicked a data associated with them get displayed?

Comment: you can do that in same way. Only difference will be that instead of `electData.category` you can use that object.

Comment: So i did this ``` first: function(categoryId){
        if(this.catt1 = this.electCats.data1.filter((obj) => obj.cat_id === categoryId)){
            this.option1 = !this.option1
            this.option2 = false
        }
        if(this.catt2 = this.electCats.data2.filter((obj) => obj.cat_id === categoryId)){
            this.option2 = !this.option2
            this.option1 = false
        }``` not working as expected

Comment: `this.electCats.data1.filter((obj) => obj.cat_id === categoryId)` will return an array and you are comparing this array with `this.catt1` which is not correct. Instead of filter you should use `.find` and then access the categoryId from an object to compare. For Ex : `this.electCats.data1.find((obj) => obj.cat_id === categoryId).category_id`

Answer (score 1):

I would v-for on the `<tr>` element, something like:

```
<tr v-for "(category, index) in electCats.category" :key="index" > 
    <td class="clickOption" @click="categoryClick(index)">{{ (category.cat_desc) }}</td>
    <td>{{ category.kwh_used }}</td>
    <td>£{{ category.cost }}</td> 
</tr>
```

Where `categoryClick()` is the function induced by clicking a row. You probably want to pass a parameter into the @click-induced function, perhaps the index, so that the function knows which element you have clicked on.